# Building MST network from adjacency matrix and adding communities in R

Tags: r, igraph, prims-algorithm

I am wanting to build a graph from an adjacency matrix of min-hash values representing pairwise distance between 46 genomes. I am fairly new to networking so am unsure if the approach I have taken does not violate any assumptions ect.

```
# build the graph object
network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(dismat, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE) # building network

mstNetwork = mst(network, weights = E(network)$weights, algorithm = "prim") # Performing Prims MST on network

# plot it

mstLayout = layout.fruchterman.reingold(mstNetwork) # setting layout

mstNetwork.com = fastgreedy.community(mstNetwork) # generating communities

V(mstNetwork)$color = mstNetwork.com$membership # setting community to colour

plot(mstNetwork, layout = mstLayout, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size = 5) # Ploting
```

Is this method sound?

My main concerns are around the community clustering as I know the `fastgreedy.community` method is normally an exploratory and not final but I am unsure which to use after.

Secondly is it allowed to perform `fastgreedy.community` or other such community algorithms on a MST?
[image]

*The dismat*

```
structure(c(0, 0.215016, 0.185827, 0.171263, 0.204284, 0.179364, 
0.175137, 0.209345, 0.200976, 0.107331, 0.177395, 0.175878, 0.197886, 
0.202933, 0.184014, 0.211692, 0.195553, 0.213325, 0.204974, 0.178964, 
0.165549, 0.0261931, 0.181002, 0.0250965, 0.176252, 0.184461, 
0.206387, 0.209345, 0.0580669, 0.206387, 0.0252653, 0.208588, 
0.200342, 0.205675, 0.202933, 0.193331, 0.207109, 0.207109, 0.192258, 
0.180176, 0.179768, 0.177011, 0.115365, 0.0454514, 0.207842, 
0.0528548, 0.215016, 0, 0.205675, 0.227796, 0.177782, 0.211692, 
0.207109, 0.239237, 0.209345, 0.207842, 0.212502, 0.208588, 0.159933, 
0.231311, 0.207109, 0.176252, 0.15863, 0.178567, 0.166759, 0.210114, 
0.184461, 0.215016, 0.204974, 0.218593, 0.210897, 0.242205, 0.16615, 
0.172635, 0.215016, 0.236445, 0.213325, 0.174771, 0.202933, 0.203604, 
0.22668, 0.22559, 0.228939, 0.175506, 0.223483, 0.204284, 0.211692, 
0.208588, 0.213325, 0.177011, 0.0194097, 0.216771, 0.185827, 
0.205675, 0, 0.194429, 0.227796, 0.0142772, 0.0346079, 0.181421, 
0.160465, 0.178567, 0.0340804, 0.0348582, 0.211692, 0.22559, 
0.00472448, 0.222464, 0.207842, 0.233808, 0.215885, 0.033903, 
0.201619, 0.18918, 0.11676, 0.190183, 0.0345062, 0.222464, 0.217673, 
0.227796, 0.191209, 0.185827, 0.185367, 0.224525, 0.154223, 0.168002, 
0.219531, 0.212502, 0.227796, 0.220489, 0.172984, 0.0148814, 
0.0329036, 0.0347669, 0.183134, 0.185367, 0.197886, 0.192791, 
0.171263, 0.227796, 0.194429, 0, 0.22559, 0.192791, 0.193331, 
0.220489, 0.202271, 0.161822, 0.194988, 0.194988, 0.213325, 0.200342, 
0.194988, 0.231311, 0.219531, 0.233808, 0.223483, 0.194988, 0.175137, 
0.174771, 0.193331, 0.171602, 0.196705, 0.161822, 0.219531, 0.224525, 
0.169279, 0.213325, 0.171944, 0.210897, 0.205675, 0.213325, 0.197292, 
0.193331, 0.211692, 0.217673, 0.200976, 0.188197, 0.196126, 0.196126, 
0.159669, 0.185827, 0.217673, 0.163504, 0.204284, 0.177782, 0.227796, 
0.22559, 0, 0.224525, 0.222464, 0.221466, 0.222464, 0.197886, 
0.22668, 0.222464, 0.171944, 0.245371, 0.227796, 0.174771, 0.16437, 
0.17663, 0.181002, 0.22668, 0.224525, 0.207109, 0.223483, 0.205675, 
0.224525, 0.23011, 0.17026, 0.169279, 0.210897, 0.22559, 0.207842, 
0.154692, 0.22668, 0.240698, 0.247037, 0.235108, 0.245371, 0.163504, 
0.218593, 0.217673, 0.224525, 0.222464, 0.204974, 0.178567, 0.175506, 
0.212502, 0.179364, 0.211692, 0.0142772, 0.192791, 0.224525, 
0, 0.0321452, 0.178567, 0.156619, 0.172635, 0.0316915, 0.0325746, 
0.207109, 0.219531, 0.0148291, 0.219531, 0.205675, 0.228939, 
0.219531, 0.031508, 0.194988, 0.183572, 0.113166, 0.184014, 0.0320311, 
0.211692, 0.213325, 0.222464, 0.192258, 0.184461, 0.181002, 0.224525, 
0.154223, 0.168318, 0.217673, 0.208588, 0.220489, 0.217673, 0.169931, 
0.0132913, 0.0313257, 0.032218, 0.179364, 0.182699, 0.196705, 
0.190693, 0.175137, 0.207109, 0.0346079, 0.193331, 0.222464, 
0.0321452, 0, 0.174048, 0.158119, 0.164955, 0.0174938, 0.00557568, 
0.206387, 0.210114, 0.0343261, 0.217673, 0.201619, 0.220489, 
0.218593, 0.0180468, 0.190183, 0.180176, 0.113166, 0.178173, 
0.0177716, 0.213325, 0.214163, 0.215885, 0.186761, 0.177782, 
0.17663, 0.223483, 0.153298, 0.169604, 0.211692, 0.202271, 0.219531, 
0.210897, 0.168956, 0.0328716, 0.0174058, 0.00592222, 0.172635, 
0.185367, 0.197292, 0.187235, 0.209345, 0.239237, 0.181421, 0.220489, 
0.221466, 0.178567, 0.174048, 0, 0.156373, 0.193877, 0.176252, 
0.174048, 0.209345, 0.239237, 0.178964, 0.23782, 0.23011, 0.245371, 
0.227796, 0.177011, 0.221466, 0.214163, 0.178173, 0.211692, 0.177782, 
0.23011, 0.220489, 0.221466, 0.215885, 0.0557338, 0.210897, 0.215016, 
0.172288, 0.169931, 0.243761, 0.22559, 0.240698, 0.214163, 0.136788, 
0.178173, 0.180176, 0.174408, 0.200342, 0.214163, 0.239237, 0.216771, 
0.200976, 0.209345, 0.160465, 0.202271, 0.222464, 0.156619, 0.158119, 
0.156373, 0, 0.188197, 0.159933, 0.158119, 0.199716, 0.236445, 
0.160465, 0.223483, 0.196126, 0.22668, 0.235108, 0.158887, 0.202271, 
0.203604, 0.161003, 0.201619, 0.157613, 0.215016, 0.220489, 0.233808, 
0.199098, 0.156619, 0.199098, 0.22559, 0.14791, 0.0666486, 0.227796, 
0.219531, 0.23782, 0.218593, 0.151504, 0.159933, 0.156129, 0.15863, 
0.200342, 0.207842, 0.207842, 0.200976, 0.107331, 0.207842, 0.178567, 
0.161822, 0.197886, 0.172635, 0.164955, 0.193877, 0.188197, 0, 
0.167376, 0.16615, 0.194429, 0.198488, 0.178964, 0.200342, 0.191731, 
0.205675, 0.200342, 0.167067, 0.164955, 0.110368, 0.173691, 0.10807, 
0.167376, 0.175878, 0.197886, 0.195553, 0.112152, 0.197886, 0.108153, 
0.198488, 0.189679, 0.200342, 0.198488, 0.189679, 0.207109, 0.198488, 
0.18918, 0.178173, 0.168318, 0.168002, 0.0204722, 0.130424, 0.199098, 
0.111519, 0.177395, 0.212502, 0.0340804, 0.194988, 0.22668, 0.0316915, 
0.0174938, 0.176252, 0.159933, 0.167376, 0, 0.0172773, 0.204974, 
0.213325, 0.0335952, 0.218593, 0.204284, 0.23011, 0.216771, 0.0178133, 
0.193331, 0.181421, 0.114491, 0.179364, 0.00580821, 0.215016, 
0.210897, 0.216771, 0.18918, 0.178173, 0.17663, 0.219531, 0.154928, 
0.165549, 0.214163, 0.203604, 0.224525, 0.214163, 0.170592, 0.0327758, 
0.00742049, 0.0174468, 0.174771, 0.186292, 0.200342, 0.188197, 
0.175878, 0.208588, 0.0348582, 0.194988, 0.222464, 0.0325746, 
0.00557568, 0.174048, 0.158119, 0.16615, 0.0172773, 0, 0.208588, 
0.213325, 0.0346987, 0.216771, 0.201619, 0.22559, 0.215016, 0.0179867, 
0.191731, 0.181002, 0.113918, 0.178567, 0.0174409, 0.211692, 
0.211692, 0.216771, 0.186761, 0.178173, 0.17663, 0.219531, 0.154692, 
0.17026, 0.213325, 0.204284, 0.222464, 0.211692, 0.170926, 0.0333339, 
0.0173824, 0.00589198, 0.173336, 0.184912, 0.199098, 0.187235, 
0.197886, 0.159933, 0.211692, 0.213325, 0.171944, 0.207109, 0.206387, 
0.209345, 0.199716, 0.194429, 0.204974, 0.208588, 0, 0.146509, 
0.211692, 0.159933, 0.15399, 0.16322, 0.161274, 0.205675, 0.197292, 
0.202271, 0.203604, 0.200976, 0.204284, 0.224525, 0.139745, 0.166453, 
0.204974, 0.217673, 0.199098, 0.10725, 0.188197, 0.200342, 0.136, 
0.212502, 0.208588, 0.106365, 0.212502, 0.207842, 0.207109, 0.207109, 
0.159407, 0.168956, 0.159669, 0.205675, 0.202933, 0.231311, 0.22559, 
0.200342, 0.245371, 0.219531, 0.210114, 0.239237, 0.236445, 0.198488, 
0.213325, 0.213325, 0.146509, 0, 0.22559, 0.232543, 0.228939, 
0.242205, 0.233808, 0.217673, 0.208588, 0.201619, 0.221466, 0.202271, 
0.211692, 0.211692, 0.13759, 0.245371, 0.207842, 0.235108, 0.199098, 
0.239237, 0.215016, 0.250557, 0.0248096, 0.130286, 0.108822, 
0.248764, 0.228939, 0.22559, 0.214163, 0.212502, 0.168002, 0.215016, 
0.233808, 0.204284, 0.184014, 0.207109, 0.00472448, 0.194988, 
0.227796, 0.0148291, 0.0343261, 0.178964, 0.160465, 0.178964, 
0.0335952, 0.0346987, 0.211692, 0.22559, 0, 0.219531, 0.206387, 
0.23011, 0.215885, 0.0341695, 0.200976, 0.187235, 0.116659, 0.188197, 
0.0340027, 0.220489, 0.211692, 0.22559, 0.191209, 0.185367, 0.183572, 
0.224525, 0.152843, 0.167067, 0.218593, 0.208588, 0.22668, 0.218593, 
0.171263, 0.0148553, 0.0325851, 0.0345175, 0.181421, 0.184912, 
0.196705, 0.190693, 0.211692, 0.176252, 0.222464, 0.231311, 0.174771, 
0.219531, 0.217673, 0.23782, 0.223483, 0.200342, 0.218593, 0.216771, 
0.159933, 0.232543, 0.219531, 0, 0.161274, 0.0435568, 0.132399, 
0.217673, 0.214163, 0.212502, 0.216771, 0.210897, 0.215885, 0.228939, 
0.13342, 0.133864, 0.215885, 0.235108, 0.211692, 0.175137, 0.212502, 
0.221466, 0.23782, 0.22559, 0.243761, 0.173336, 0.223483, 0.217673, 
0.213325, 0.216771, 0.208588, 0.145921, 0.168636, 0.214163, 0.195553, 
0.15863, 0.207842, 0.219531, 0.16437, 0.205675, 0.201619, 0.23011, 
0.196126, 0.191731, 0.204284, 0.201619, 0.15399, 0.228939, 0.206387, 
0.161274, 0, 0.167067, 0.165848, 0.204974, 0.203604, 0.198488, 
0.180176, 0.199098, 0.204974, 0.212502, 0.165549, 0.16615, 0.172635, 
0.227796, 0.202271, 0.170926, 0.201619, 0.204974, 0.213325, 0.213325, 
0.222464, 0.169279, 0.215885, 0.174048, 0.202933, 0.201619, 0.200342, 
0.174771, 0.14291, 0.201619, 0.213325, 0.178567, 0.233808, 0.233808, 
0.17663, 0.228939, 0.220489, 0.245371, 0.22668, 0.205675, 0.23011, 
0.22559, 0.16322, 0.242205, 0.23011, 0.0435568, 0.167067, 0, 
0.135072, 0.228939, 0.214163, 0.215885, 0.210114, 0.215016, 0.228939, 
0.231311, 0.135072, 0.136157, 0.215885, 0.236445, 0.213325, 0.172635, 
0.213325, 0.227796, 0.239237, 0.222464, 0.248764, 0.174408, 0.233808, 
0.22668, 0.22668, 0.22559, 0.216771, 0.145341, 0.172635, 0.215016, 
0.204974, 0.166759, 0.215885, 0.223483, 0.181002, 0.219531, 0.218593, 
0.227796, 0.235108, 0.200342, 0.216771, 0.215016, 0.161274, 0.233808, 
0.215885, 0.132399, 0.165848, 0.135072, 0, 0.217673, 0.223483, 
0.208588, 0.208588, 0.208588, 0.219531, 0.233808, 0.0713864, 
0.116659, 0.215016, 0.228939, 0.207842, 0.177782, 0.220489, 0.235108, 
0.23782, 0.232543, 0.236445, 0.178964, 0.227796, 0.213325, 0.218593, 
0.215885, 0.207109, 0.0290769, 0.164079, 0.214163, 0.178964, 
0.210114, 0.033903, 0.194988, 0.22668, 0.031508, 0.0180468, 0.177011, 
0.158887, 0.167067, 0.0178133, 0.0179867, 0.205675, 0.217673, 
0.0341695, 0.217673, 0.204974, 0.228939, 0.217673, 0, 0.193877, 
0.184912, 0.11566, 0.181843, 0.0178909, 0.217673, 0.212502, 0.219531, 
0.191209, 0.178567, 0.179364, 0.22668, 0.156619, 0.168636, 0.216771, 
0.207109, 0.218593, 0.213325, 0.170592, 0.0329999, 0.0179687, 
0.0181313, 0.175878, 0.186292, 0.202271, 0.192791, 0.165549, 
0.184461, 0.201619, 0.175137, 0.224525, 0.194988, 0.190183, 0.221466, 
0.202271, 0.164955, 0.193331, 0.191731, 0.197292, 0.208588, 0.200976, 
0.214163, 0.203604, 0.214163, 0.223483, 0.193877, 0, 0.168956, 
0.200342, 0.168318, 0.194429, 0.187713, 0.210897, 0.210114, 0.168636, 
0.216771, 0.169604, 0.216771, 0.207842, 0.208588, 0.206387, 0.195553, 
0.214163, 0.219531, 0.206387, 0.199098, 0.194988, 0.191209, 0.172288, 
0.185827, 0.204284, 0.171602, 0.0261931, 0.215016, 0.18918, 0.174771, 
0.207109, 0.183572, 0.180176, 0.214163, 0.203604, 0.110368, 0.181421, 
0.181002, 0.202271, 0.201619, 0.187235, 0.212502, 0.198488, 0.215885, 
0.208588, 0.184912, 0.168956, 0, 0.184014, 0.0253542, 0.181843, 
0.188197, 0.207109, 0.212502, 0.0613777, 0.207842, 0.0252653, 
0.210897, 0.204974, 0.207109, 0.202271, 0.193877, 0.206387, 0.210897, 
0.197886, 0.185827, 0.183134, 0.182269, 0.117681, 0.0469534, 
0.207842, 0.0550181, 0.181002, 0.204974, 0.11676, 0.193331, 0.223483, 
0.113166, 0.113166, 0.178173, 0.161003, 0.173691, 0.114491, 0.113918, 
0.203604, 0.221466, 0.116659, 0.216771, 0.180176, 0.210114, 0.208588, 
0.11566, 0.200342, 0.184014, 0, 0.184912, 0.114684, 0.209345, 
0.210897, 0.212502, 0.169279, 0.179364, 0.181002, 0.222464, 0.146116, 
0.168318, 0.214163, 0.213325, 0.233808, 0.218593, 0.169604, 0.110368, 
0.114204, 0.114204, 0.17663, 0.184461, 0.178567, 0.185827, 0.0250965, 
0.218593, 0.190183, 0.171602, 0.205675, 0.184014, 0.178173, 0.211692, 
0.201619, 0.10807, 0.179364, 0.178567, 0.200976, 0.202271, 0.188197, 
0.210897, 0.199098, 0.215016, 0.208588, 0.181843, 0.168318, 0.0253542, 
0.184912, 0, 0.178964, 0.181421, 0.205675, 0.210897, 0.0600164, 
0.210114, 0.0248969, 0.212502, 0.205675, 0.207842, 0.199716, 
0.195553, 0.204284, 0.211692, 0.195553, 0.186292, 0.181843, 0.179364, 
0.116157, 0.0458408, 0.207842, 0.0543589, 0.176252, 0.210897, 
0.0345062, 0.196705, 0.224525, 0.0320311, 0.0177716, 0.177782, 
0.157613, 0.167376, 0.00580821, 0.0174409, 0.204284, 0.211692, 
0.0340027, 0.215885, 0.204974, 0.228939, 0.219531, 0.0178909, 
0.194429, 0.181843, 0.114684, 0.178964, 0, 0.213325, 0.212502, 
0.217673, 0.187235, 0.178964, 0.177782, 0.219531, 0.154928, 0.16615, 
0.215016, 0.201619, 0.224525, 0.212502, 0.17026, 0.0332581, 0.00710613, 
0.0175821, 0.175137, 0.186292, 0.199716, 0.187235, 0.184461, 
0.242205, 0.222464, 0.161822, 0.23011, 0.211692, 0.213325, 0.23011, 
0.215016, 0.175878, 0.215016, 0.211692, 0.224525, 0.211692, 0.220489, 
0.228939, 0.212502, 0.231311, 0.233808, 0.217673, 0.187713, 0.188197, 
0.209345, 0.181421, 0.213325, 0, 0.239237, 0.23782, 0.178173, 
0.22559, 0.181843, 0.22668, 0.213325, 0.227796, 0.210897, 0.209345, 
0.215016, 0.224525, 0.227796, 0.214163, 0.210897, 0.212502, 0.180587, 
0.200342, 0.22559, 0.178173, 0.206387, 0.16615, 0.217673, 0.219531, 
0.17026, 0.213325, 0.214163, 0.220489, 0.220489, 0.197886, 0.210897, 
0.211692, 0.139745, 0.13759, 0.211692, 0.13342, 0.165549, 0.135072, 
0.0713864, 0.212502, 0.210897, 0.207109, 0.210897, 0.205675, 
0.212502, 0.239237, 0, 0.117065, 0.210114, 0.220489, 0.203604, 
0.176252, 0.182269, 0.214163, 0.124977, 0.202933, 0.194988, 0.174048, 
0.236445, 0.204974, 0.215016, 0.211692, 0.151946, 0.081352, 0.162376, 
0.207842, 0.209345, 0.172635, 0.227796, 0.224525, 0.169279, 0.222464, 
0.215885, 0.221466, 0.233808, 0.195553, 0.216771, 0.216771, 0.166453, 
0.245371, 0.22559, 0.133864, 0.16615, 0.136157, 0.116659, 0.219531, 
0.210114, 0.212502, 0.212502, 0.210897, 0.217673, 0.23782, 0.117065, 
0, 0.214163, 0.213325, 0.207109, 0.157113, 0.214163, 0.227796, 
0.23782, 0.228939, 0.245371, 0.159933, 0.221466, 0.220489, 0.220489, 
0.217673, 0.199716, 0.124977, 0.166453, 0.209345, 0.0580669, 
0.215016, 0.191209, 0.169279, 0.210897, 0.192258, 0.186761, 0.215885, 
0.199098, 0.112152, 0.18918, 0.186761, 0.204974, 0.207842, 0.191209, 
0.215885, 0.172635, 0.215885, 0.215016, 0.191209, 0.168636, 0.0613777, 
0.169279, 0.0600164, 0.187235, 0.178173, 0.210114, 0.214163, 
0, 0.209345, 0.0598929, 0.214163, 0.204284, 0.206387, 0.200976, 
0.195553, 0.209345, 0.215885, 0.202933, 0.171602, 0.189679, 0.187235, 
0.117992, 0.0797333, 0.186761, 0.0358812, 0.206387, 0.236445, 
0.185827, 0.213325, 0.22559, 0.184461, 0.177782, 0.0557338, 0.156619, 
0.197886, 0.178173, 0.178173, 0.217673, 0.235108, 0.185367, 0.235108, 
0.227796, 0.236445, 0.228939, 0.178567, 0.216771, 0.207842, 0.179364, 
0.210114, 0.178964, 0.22559, 0.220489, 0.213325, 0.209345, 0, 
0.205675, 0.215885, 0.174048, 0.169604, 0.23782, 0.209345, 0.250557, 
0.221466, 0.138572, 0.184461, 0.180587, 0.178964, 0.200342, 0.212502, 
0.227796, 0.214163, 0.0252653, 0.213325, 0.185367, 0.171944, 
0.207842, 0.181002, 0.17663, 0.210897, 0.199098, 0.108153, 0.17663, 
0.17663, 0.199098, 0.199098, 0.183572, 0.211692, 0.202271, 0.213325, 
0.207842, 0.179364, 0.169604, 0.0252653, 0.181002, 0.0248969, 
0.177782, 0.181843, 0.203604, 0.207109, 0.0598929, 0.205675, 
0, 0.207109, 0.200976, 0.204974, 0.199716, 0.190693, 0.203604, 
0.207842, 0.195553, 0.182699, 0.179364, 0.177782, 0.115858, 0.0455321, 
0.205675, 0.0553849, 0.208588, 0.174771, 0.224525, 0.210897, 
0.154692, 0.224525, 0.223483, 0.215016, 0.22559, 0.198488, 0.219531, 
0.219531, 0.10725, 0.239237, 0.224525, 0.175137, 0.170926, 0.172635, 
0.177782, 0.22668, 0.216771, 0.210897, 0.222464, 0.212502, 0.219531, 
0.22668, 0.176252, 0.157113, 0.214163, 0.215885, 0.207109, 0, 
0.22559, 0.227796, 0.232543, 0.23782, 0.247037, 0.0241909, 0.202933, 
0.218593, 0.224525, 0.219531, 0.197292, 0.183572, 0.174771, 0.211692, 
0.200342, 0.202933, 0.154223, 0.205675, 0.22668, 0.154223, 0.153298, 
0.172288, 0.14791, 0.189679, 0.154928, 0.154692, 0.188197, 0.215016, 
0.152843, 0.212502, 0.201619, 0.213325, 0.220489, 0.156619, 0.207842, 
0.204974, 0.146116, 0.205675, 0.154928, 0.213325, 0.182269, 0.214163, 
0.204284, 0.174048, 0.200976, 0.22559, 0, 0.147104, 0.190693, 
0.205675, 0.223483, 0.219531, 0.16615, 0.150633, 0.151725, 0.156373, 
0.181002, 0.202933, 0.204284, 0.201619, 0.205675, 0.203604, 0.168002, 
0.213325, 0.240698, 0.168318, 0.169604, 0.169931, 0.0666486, 
0.200342, 0.165549, 0.17026, 0.200342, 0.250557, 0.167067, 0.221466, 
0.204974, 0.227796, 0.235108, 0.168636, 0.208588, 0.207109, 0.168318, 
0.207842, 0.16615, 0.227796, 0.214163, 0.227796, 0.206387, 0.169604, 
0.204974, 0.227796, 0.147104, 0, 0.240698, 0.222464, 0.247037, 
0.224525, 0.156129, 0.165251, 0.166453, 0.170926, 0.206387, 0.213325, 
0.203604, 0.206387, 0.202933, 0.22668, 0.219531, 0.197292, 0.247037, 
0.217673, 0.211692, 0.243761, 0.227796, 0.198488, 0.214163, 0.213325, 
0.136, 0.0248096, 0.218593, 0.23782, 0.213325, 0.239237, 0.23782, 
0.216771, 0.206387, 0.202271, 0.214163, 0.199716, 0.215016, 0.210897, 
0.124977, 0.23782, 0.200976, 0.23782, 0.199716, 0.232543, 0.190693, 
0.240698, 0, 0.128007, 0.10807, 0.240698, 0.22668, 0.217673, 
0.211692, 0.213325, 0.153758, 0.210897, 0.224525, 0.197886, 0.193331, 
0.22559, 0.212502, 0.193331, 0.235108, 0.208588, 0.202271, 0.22559, 
0.219531, 0.189679, 0.203604, 0.204284, 0.212502, 0.130286, 0.208588, 
0.22559, 0.213325, 0.222464, 0.232543, 0.207109, 0.195553, 0.193877, 
0.213325, 0.195553, 0.201619, 0.209345, 0.202933, 0.228939, 0.195553, 
0.209345, 0.190693, 0.23782, 0.205675, 0.222464, 0.128007, 0, 
0.13342, 0.231311, 0.209345, 0.206387, 0.203604, 0.205675, 0.18918, 
0.201619, 0.218593, 0.190183, 0.207109, 0.228939, 0.227796, 0.211692, 
0.245371, 0.220489, 0.219531, 0.240698, 0.23782, 0.207109, 0.224525, 
0.222464, 0.208588, 0.108822, 0.22668, 0.243761, 0.222464, 0.248764, 
0.236445, 0.218593, 0.214163, 0.206387, 0.233808, 0.204284, 0.224525, 
0.215016, 0.194988, 0.245371, 0.209345, 0.250557, 0.203604, 0.247037, 
0.223483, 0.247037, 0.10807, 0.13342, 0, 0.250557, 0.231311, 
0.221466, 0.224525, 0.221466, 0.195553, 0.215885, 0.224525, 0.206387, 
0.207109, 0.175506, 0.220489, 0.217673, 0.163504, 0.217673, 0.210897, 
0.214163, 0.218593, 0.198488, 0.214163, 0.211692, 0.106365, 0.248764, 
0.218593, 0.173336, 0.169279, 0.174408, 0.178964, 0.213325, 0.219531, 
0.210897, 0.218593, 0.211692, 0.212502, 0.224525, 0.174048, 0.159933, 
0.215885, 0.221466, 0.207842, 0.0241909, 0.219531, 0.224525, 
0.240698, 0.231311, 0.250557, 0, 0.205675, 0.212502, 0.218593, 
0.210897, 0.198488, 0.181421, 0.173336, 0.217673, 0.192258, 0.223483, 
0.172984, 0.200976, 0.218593, 0.169931, 0.168956, 0.136788, 0.151504, 
0.18918, 0.170592, 0.170926, 0.212502, 0.228939, 0.171263, 0.223483, 
0.215885, 0.233808, 0.227796, 0.170592, 0.206387, 0.197886, 0.169604, 
0.195553, 0.17026, 0.227796, 0.236445, 0.221466, 0.202933, 0.138572, 
0.195553, 0.202933, 0.16615, 0.156129, 0.22668, 0.209345, 0.231311, 
0.205675, 0, 0.170926, 0.17026, 0.172635, 0.193877, 0.210897, 
0.216771, 0.205675, 0.180176, 0.204284, 0.0148814, 0.188197, 
0.217673, 0.0132913, 0.0328716, 0.178173, 0.159933, 0.178173, 
0.0327758, 0.0333339, 0.207842, 0.22559, 0.0148553, 0.217673, 
0.174048, 0.22668, 0.213325, 0.0329999, 0.199098, 0.185827, 0.110368, 
0.186292, 0.0332581, 0.214163, 0.204974, 0.220489, 0.171602, 
0.184461, 0.182699, 0.218593, 0.150633, 0.165251, 0.217673, 0.206387, 
0.221466, 0.212502, 0.170926, 0, 0.0319277, 0.0330427, 0.178964, 
0.179364, 0.175137, 0.185367, 0.179768, 0.211692, 0.0329036, 
0.196126, 0.224525, 0.0313257, 0.0174058, 0.180176, 0.156129, 
0.168318, 0.00742049, 0.0173824, 0.207109, 0.214163, 0.0325851, 
0.213325, 0.202933, 0.22668, 0.218593, 0.0179687, 0.194988, 0.183134, 
0.114204, 0.181843, 0.00710613, 0.210897, 0.215016, 0.220489, 
0.189679, 0.180587, 0.179364, 0.224525, 0.151725, 0.166453, 0.211692, 
0.203604, 0.224525, 0.218593, 0.17026, 0.0319277, 0, 0.0172541, 
0.174771, 0.184014, 0.199098, 0.186761, 0.177011, 0.208588, 0.0347669, 
0.196126, 0.222464, 0.032218, 0.00592222, 0.174408, 0.15863, 
0.168002, 0.0174468, 0.00589198, 0.207109, 0.212502, 0.0345175, 
0.216771, 0.201619, 0.22559, 0.215885, 0.0181313, 0.191209, 0.182269, 
0.114204, 0.179364, 0.0175821, 0.212502, 0.211692, 0.217673, 
0.187235, 0.178964, 0.177782, 0.219531, 0.156373, 0.170926, 0.213325, 
0.205675, 0.221466, 0.210897, 0.172635, 0.0330427, 0.0172541, 
0, 0.175506, 0.185827, 0.200342, 0.188197, 0.115365, 0.213325, 
0.183134, 0.159669, 0.204974, 0.179364, 0.172635, 0.200342, 0.200342, 
0.0204722, 0.174771, 0.173336, 0.159407, 0.168002, 0.181421, 
0.208588, 0.200342, 0.216771, 0.207109, 0.175878, 0.172288, 0.117681, 
0.17663, 0.116157, 0.175137, 0.180587, 0.151946, 0.199716, 0.117992, 
0.200342, 0.115858, 0.197292, 0.181002, 0.206387, 0.153758, 0.18918, 
0.195553, 0.198488, 0.193877, 0.178964, 0.174771, 0.175506, 0, 
0.13663, 0.207109, 0.117065, 0.0454514, 0.177011, 0.185367, 0.185827, 
0.178567, 0.182699, 0.185367, 0.214163, 0.207842, 0.130424, 0.186292, 
0.184912, 0.168956, 0.215016, 0.184912, 0.145921, 0.174771, 0.145341, 
0.0290769, 0.186292, 0.185827, 0.0469534, 0.184461, 0.0458408, 
0.186292, 0.200342, 0.081352, 0.124977, 0.0797333, 0.212502, 
0.0455321, 0.183572, 0.202933, 0.213325, 0.210897, 0.201619, 
0.215885, 0.181421, 0.210897, 0.179364, 0.184014, 0.185827, 0.13663, 
0, 0.172635, 0.0729317, 0.207842, 0.0194097, 0.197886, 0.217673, 
0.175506, 0.196705, 0.197292, 0.239237, 0.207842, 0.199098, 0.200342, 
0.199098, 0.159669, 0.233808, 0.196705, 0.168636, 0.14291, 0.172635, 
0.164079, 0.202271, 0.204284, 0.207842, 0.178567, 0.207842, 0.199716, 
0.22559, 0.162376, 0.166453, 0.186761, 0.227796, 0.205675, 0.174771, 
0.204284, 0.203604, 0.224525, 0.218593, 0.224525, 0.173336, 0.216771, 
0.175137, 0.199098, 0.200342, 0.207109, 0.172635, 0, 0.214163, 
0.0528548, 0.216771, 0.192791, 0.163504, 0.212502, 0.190693, 
0.187235, 0.216771, 0.200976, 0.111519, 0.188197, 0.187235, 0.205675, 
0.204284, 0.190693, 0.214163, 0.201619, 0.215016, 0.214163, 0.192791, 
0.171602, 0.0550181, 0.185827, 0.0543589, 0.187235, 0.178173, 
0.207842, 0.209345, 0.0358812, 0.214163, 0.0553849, 0.211692, 
0.201619, 0.206387, 0.197886, 0.190183, 0.206387, 0.217673, 0.205675, 
0.185367, 0.186761, 0.188197, 0.117065, 0.0729317, 0.214163, 
0), .Dim = c(46L, 46L), .Dimnames = list(c("IC0024", "D27", "T153", 
"D52", "GCA_003313675", "GCA_001263195", "IC0027", "GCA_001972325", 
"IC0019", "IC0035-1", "IC0001", "IC0032", "D44", "PseudaA", "T112", 
"IC0020", "D8", "D25", "IC0026", "IC0038", "D28", "ANC-D", "D12", 
"ANC-H", "IC0010", "D13", "D45", "GCA_003313785", "D10", "D59", 
"ANC-I", "GCA_003313075", "D46", "D36", "D43", "D58", "IC0035-2", 
"GCA_003316525", "GCA_003313055", "D11", "IC0034", "IC0033", 
"D42", "Micro", "D9", "D53"), c("IC0024", "D27", "T153", "D52", 
"GCA_003313675", "GCA_001263195", "IC0027", "GCA_001972325", 
"IC0019", "IC0035.1", "IC0001", "IC0032", "D44", "PseudaA", "T112", 
"IC0020", "D8", "D25", "IC0026", "IC0038", "D28", "ANC.D", "D12", 
"ANC.H", "IC0010", "D13", "D45", "GCA_003313785", "D10", "D59", 
"ANC.I", "GCA_003313075", "D46", "D36", "D43", "D58", "IC0035.2", 
"GCA_003316525", "GCA_003313055", "D11", "IC0034", "IC0033", 
"D42", "Micro", "D9", "D53")))
```

Comment: Could you `dput(dismat)` and copy/paste it to the post?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I have added it